# How to fix this WebAPI ODATA error: "Parent id or contained context url is missing which is required to compute id for contained instance"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an ODATA server built with [WebApi](http://odata.github.io/WebApi) where my container has only an entity set of 'calendars'. In turn, each 'calendar' has a navigation property which is a collection of 'appointments' and a function to 'getCalendarView', which returns a subset of such appointments. The appointments are contained in the calendar, meaning there is no entity set in the container with them.

When I call 'getCalendarView' asking for minimal metadata, I get back the results. However, if I ask for the full metadata, I get this error:

"Parent id or contained context url is missing which is required to compute id for contained instance."

If I understand this correctly, the framework does not know who is the parent calendar of the returned appointments, so it fails to produce the links that represent each entity. How can I provide this info?

The error message continues with "Specify ODataUri in the ODataMessageWriterSettings or return parent id or context url in the payload.", but I don't know how that translates to code in WebApi.

I don't have access to the ODataMessageWriterSettings in my WebApi controller (I suppose) so the first suggestion does not seem to apply. So how do I "return parent id or context url in the payload"?

Is there a way to tag the controller method or the returned entities in any way to provide the info?

If it helps, the metadata looks somewhat like this:

```
  <EntityType Name="appointment">
   ...
  </EntityType>
  <EntityType Name="calendar">
   ...
    <NavigationProperty Name="appointments" Type="Collection(appointment)" ContainsTarget="true" />
   ...
  </EntityType>

  <Function Name="getCalendarView" IsBound="true" EntitySetPath="calendar/appointments">
    <Parameter Name="calendar" Type="calendar" Nullable="false" />
    <Parameter Name="start" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
    <Parameter Name="end" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
    <ReturnType Type="Collection(appointment)" Nullable="false" />
  </Function>
  <EntityContainer Name="container">
    <EntitySet Name="calendars" EntityType="calendars" />
     ...
  </EntityContainer>
```

I'm not 100% if I'm using EntitySetPath correctly.

My controller code goes like this:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("calendars({calendarId})")]
public class CalendarController 
{
   ...

    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("getCalendarView(start={start},end={end})")]
    public Task<IQueryable<Appointment>> GetCalendarView(DateTimeOffset start, DateTimeOffset end) =>
   ...

}
```

In code, Appointment and Calendar are simple POCO classes, with their respective properties. Does they need any special property to indicate its parent id or context url?

Thanks

Comment: I've created a project that shows the repro of this problem. https://github.com/fpintos/ODataSample1

Comment: Reported as https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/917